# RS232 Splitter For PC

Tags: rs232

I have two XP machines (I know), one is an industrial XP Embedded Beckhoff CX unit, the other is a run of the mill i3 PC. Both have serial ports and both have separate Symbol hand scanners. Does a splitter exist that will allow me to plug one scanner in and route TWO serial cables, one to each machine? Will there be any 'cross talk' or communications with this method? thanks!!

Comment: You want to scan to both machines simultaneously?  Or you want to switch back and forth without unplugging?

Comment: If the scanner is just a dumb machine that spits out whatever it reads then a splitter that only connects the scanner TX and GND should work, I doubt there is a cable available to do this. But whatever this is for there is certainly a better way to do it.

Comment: Jason - Scan to both simultaneously

Comment: @user325521 - You won't find a cable like that.  USB devices can't even do this and USB is based of serial devices.

Comment: handshake , stop bits , parity?  So would the first clue come from observing the serial settings used on the computers , or settings that do not work when the device is communicating properly? Surely the manuel for the scanner has the port settings information?  While the RS232 would be a prime canidate for simple blind flow of data, I doubt a manufactured device would be a raw one way thing, without any "control"?

Comment: Yes, RS232 splitters exist, but the ones I've seen split the other way (one computer to two devices). A search for "rs232 splitter schematic" will give you tons of designs, but most aren't what you want. An RS232 tap cable might work for you, however.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about a "splitter" but what you probably want is a serial switch, allowing you to switch which machine the serial device is plugged into at the flick of a.. well.. switch ^^

Something like:
http://www.fruitycables.co.uk/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=278&gclid=CKe77d2pvb4CFSMUwwodUVoAjA

Comment: OP here. I actually want the scan to send the data to both PCs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on if the hand scanners need feedback form the computer it is connected to or not.

If the hand scanner just "broadcasts" its data and receives ***absolutely no input*** from the computer it is attached to you could just solder two sets of wires together and make a Y cable. However if there is any communication at all from the computer going to the hand scanner this method will not work at all.

You will need to find out about the protocol the hand scanner uses and find out if there is any two way communication or not. If there is any two way communication what you want to do is not easily solvable (not without custom hardware sitting in between the scanner and the two computers) you will not find any solutions for this "off the shelf" to be able to broadcast at the same time.

Your better option is hook up some kind of switch (many [KVM switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) have a serial port on them) that will let you easily switch which one of the two devices the hand scanner is connected to without needing to physically unplug the scanner from one machine to the other. This is not "at the same time" like you wanted but it does ease switching computers.

Comment: The scanner is a Symbol 2208, looking through the product manual I'm not seeing any reference to its broadcast method.

Comment: I doubt it will be in the product manual, you will need to go get the SDK from the manufacture to find out. This will likely involve skill in programming to verify.

Comment: @user325521 If you can't get the SDK you could also do an experiment. Build an RS232 cable (or modify an existing one) so that only RX and GND are connected. (Not TX, that would be data from computer to device.) If the scanner works with that cable, it ought to work with a splitter.